# Por que mi boton toggle navbar en bootstrap no funciona?

Tags: bootstrap, navbar

Copie y pegue botones y de igual manera sigue sin funcionar, ademas de que intento moverlo todo hacia la derecha pero tampoco puedo, que puedo hacer? Estoy usando Angular

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="nav">
<div class="container-fluid" id="navbar">
    <app-logo-ap class="navbar-brand"></app-logo-ap>

    <!-- boton del menu -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler w-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menu" aria-controls="#menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- elementos del menu colapsable -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">EXPERIENCE</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">EDUCATION</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">PROYECTS</a></li>
        </ul>
        <app-social></app-social>
      </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente sea porque no tienes las clases principales para ajustar el `nav` de Bootstrap:

```
navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light
```

O también puede que no estés importando bien las librerías, todo dependerá de la versión que uses.

Ejemplo en Bootstrap v5:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="nav">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="navbar">

    <!-- boton del menu -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler w-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menu" aria-controls="#menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- elementos del menu colapsable -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">EXPERIENCE</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">EDUCATION</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">PROYECTS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>    
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```